# Disable auto import optimization on refactor in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using PyCharm's refactor (`Refactor -> Move File...`), and I want him to just change all usages in import statements, but beside that the moving also trigger the Import optimization and delete other imports.

Is there a way to disable the auto import optimization on refactor in PyCharm?